# Python Importar desde otra carpeta no me funciona

Tags: python

Llevo tiempo con esta cuestión y he reunido desde la red y un amable colaborador  de Stack Overflow no menos de 15 soluciones pero no me funciona ninguna. Ruego la solución a este caso. Mi aplicación está como pongo
C:\users\pepe\documents\Proyecto0

Proyecto0
|

|--- Models

```
 |---Product.py
 |---User.py
```

|----Database

```
 |---Connection.py
```

|----Views

```
 |--- Principal.py
 |----Login.py 
 |----CreateProduct.py
```

|----Controllers

```
 |----CreateProductController.py
 |--- LoginController.py
 |--- PrincipalCcontroller.py
```

Situado en CreateProductController quiero

```
 from Database.Connection import connection  
 from Models.Product import Product
```

o situado en Principal.py

```
from Controllers.PrincipalController import PrincipalController
```

En el principio de cada archivo tengo puesto

import sys

import os

myDir=os.getcwd

sys.path.append(myDir)

He probado todos los path imaginables, desde C:..., desde Proyecto0, con . y con .. Es igual, siempre recibo "No se ha encontrado el módulo" de donde quiero importar y si pongo como origen del path "Proyecto0" recibo el mensaje de que Proyecto0 no es un directorio parent. Con enlazar una vez con otra carpeta, se habrá solucionado totalmente el problema que me tiene parado.
Si pongo

sys.path.insert(C:.....\Proyecto0)
recibo el error

"Import Module Product could not be resolved".
Si pongo

sys.path.append(myDir)
recibo el error

No module named Product".
Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Cual es el entry point de tu código? cual es el archivo main? Si conviertes el código a un módulo con su \_\_init\_\_.py es sencillo. En cualquier caso: `from .. import Database.Connection`.  Una mejor manera sería lanzar la aplicación desde el entry point y así todos los imports son hacia childs, no hacia parents. No inventes tu propia manera de hacer algo cuando existe una forma sencilla.

Comment: Si no es un invento mío, es una aplicación que está en la red como un ejercicio (BERCKBEL)y le funciona al autor, pero no a mí. La entrada a la aplicación es un archivo login.py que llama a Controllers.loginController y no lo "engancha".

Comment: login.py llama a /principal,) que está en el mismo directorio  y lo enlñaza, y además llama a controllers,LoginControler( iews

Comment: Sigo. cuando ejecuto login.py este llama a principal, que está en la misma carpeta, y lo coge sin problema, además llama a "from Controllers.LoginController import LoginController". Este archivo llama a Database.connection y como consecuencia recibo el mensasje de error: no se ha podido enlazar con el módulo Database.. Es decir, no he podido importar desde Database.connection hacia LoginController. Un lío.

Comment: Los módulos módulos no deben estar bien definidos o te falta el python que hace la ubicación de todos los módulos. Pero puedes hacer  `from ..Database.Connection import connection` en el archivo CreateProductController. Nota los `..` del from import. Es para subir al directorio padre. Lo op5imo es que definas tus módulos correctamente. Si dices que a la otra persona le funciona es porque debe tener un archivo que tu no tienes. Prueba gon la notación.. para empezar

Comment: Juan Carlos Guibovich: Muchísimas gracias, me has sacado de un atolladero. He hecho dos cosas según tus indicaciones: a) Ver si me faltaba algo. No había copiado los archivos __pycache__ de cada carpeta. Los he copiado. b) He puesto los dos puntos de subida al directorio padre y ¡voila! han desaparecido todos los errores y los subrayados acusadores. Repito, mil gracias,. Voy a ver por dónde puedo calificar tu excelente ayuda. Gracias también a los otros amables informantes, pero mi poca ciencia no me ha permitido entender bien loque me han dicho.  Que tengas un buen día, Alberto .